# dynamic collections with node.js and monogjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dynamic, mongojs

i try to find a way to use vars for mongojs collections.
The data are dynamic and also the db.VAR.find(); must
be dynamic. Is there a solution for that problem. I
searched here and google, but there is nothing.
I hope you can help me.

Example:

```
var var1 = "game12"; var var2 = "game34";

db.***var1***.find({name: x},function(err, datas) {
     if( err || !datas ) {
        console.log("Problem finding data :" + err);
     }else{
         datas.forEach( function(curData) {
            console.log(curData);
         });
     } });


db.***var2***.find({name: x},function(err, datas) {
     if( err || !datas ) {
        console.log("Problem finding data :" + err);
     }else{
         datas.forEach( function(curData) {
            console.log(curData);
         });
     } });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db[var1].find(...`

`db[var2].find(...`

Comment: Wow, thats fast! Thank you very much.. I will try it!